# prev/next links to show whats on different page in php

Tags: php, css, session-variables, pagination

Okay so I have found after some long research a code that I will include here that adds prev/next url at bottom of page. What I am doing is making a portfolio that in the future I will add pages and remove, so I needed a php code that would run pages using the footer.php and go to next in line. Example it would show page1.php, page2.php, page3.php, page4.php and so on. That all works great in the code I have. What I would like now is to put a variable name on each page of what that portfolio piece will be then have it echo next to the previous and next button. I can get it to work, but it shows the existing name on each prev/next button.

If I am not making sense just tell me and I will explain it differently. I hope someone can help, been trying to get my portfolio done for some time now! :)

Here is my header.php

```
<html>

<head>

<title>PAGINATION TEST</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />    

</head> 

<nav>

    <div id="nav_menu">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</nav>    

<body>
```

Here is my page1.php

```
<?php //THIS IS THE PREVIOUS/NEXT LINK TITLE FOR EACH PORTFOLIO PAGE
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['link-title'] = "wonder woman";
?>

<?php include('header.php') ?>

<div id="main_body">
PAGE 1
</div>

<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

Here is my footer.php

```
<?php 
    session_start(); //this NEEDS to be at top of the page before any output etc
?>

<?php

$pinfo = pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
$reqpath = dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

$linkname = ($_SESSION['link-title']);

if(preg_match("/(.*?)(\d+)\.php/", $pinfo["basename"], $matches)) {
    $fnbase = $matches[1];
    $fndir = $pinfo["dirname"];

    $linkTitle = $linkname;

    $current = intval($matches[2]);
    $next = $current + 1;
    $prior = $current - 1;
    $next_file = $fndir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fnbase . $next . ".php";
    $prior_file = $fndir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fnbase . $prior . ".php";

    $next_link = $linkTitle . $next;
    $prev_link = $linkTitle . $prior;

    if(!file_exists($next_file)) $next_file = false;
    if(!file_exists($prior_file)) $prior_file = false;

    if($prior_file) {
        $link = $reqpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($prior_file);

      //  echo "<a href=\"$link\">Prior</a>";
    }

    if($prior_file && $next_file) {
      //  echo " / ";
    }

    if($next_file) {
        $link = $reqpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($next_file);

       // echo "<a href=\"$link\">Next</a>";
    }

    if($prev_link) {
        $prevTitle = $prev_link;

    }

    if($next_link) {
        $Title =  $next_link;

    }



}

?>

<div id="pagination_container">

    <div id="previous_link">
       <!-- <a href="#back" class="backLink" id="backLink">PREVIOUS</a> -->
        <?php if($prior_file) {
        $link = $reqpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($prior_file);

        echo "<a href=\"$link\">PREVIOUS</a>";
       // echo $_SESSION['link-title'];    
        echo $prevTitle;

        }

         ?>

    </div>

    <div id="next_link">
        <!-- <a href="#next" class="nextLink" id="nextLink">NEXT</a> -->
        <?php if($next_file) {
        $link = $reqpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($next_file);

        echo $Title;
       // echo $_SESSION['link-title'];
        echo "<a href=\"$link\">NEXT</a>";

        }
        ?>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

    copyright blah blah

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

here is my css

```
body,html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#nav_menu {
    background-color: pink; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

#nav_menu ul {
   text-align: right;
}

#nav_menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#main_body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #333333;
}

#pagination_container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
}

#previous_link {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#previous_link:hover {
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}

#previous_link:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#next_link {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

#next_link a:visited {
    color: white;
}

#next_link a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#next_link a:hover {
    color: blue;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}

#next_link:hover {
    background-color: pink;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Here is page2.php for example of how it works now

```
<?php //THIS IS THE PREVIOUS/NEXT LINK TITLE FOR EACH PORTFOLIO PAGE
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['link-title'] = "superman";
?>

<?php include('header.php') ?>

<div id="main_body">
PAGE 2
</div>

<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: so how is the $current value set?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how it works... still learning a lot about php, I just found that code on this website and it started working how I needed it to.

Comment: there is not $current value set and if its set, it should be as a session variable

Comment: how do I go about doing that? sounds kinda confusing to me. Is that what would pass the variable to show the print out of the next pages info I want?

Comment: okay coder.. I have done more research and tried some things. I updated my code and this is getting me closer! Right now when you make a couple of portfoliopage_ in number order they work. Right now it is giving me a title of superman next to the previous and next link. It should be whats on the page before and the page after, not the same pages SESSION. What am I doing wrong here? i assumed by using the $next and $prior it would do the same as when sorting what page. next to the superman text I end up getting a 1 on the previous or a 3 on the next but not for the main link title.